# WordPress conditional statement for front-page or inner page

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I need help with the templating in wordpress.

On the front-page I want a custom static header, while all the other pages should use the title for their page instead.
Also, if the page is not the front-page I want to add some custom HTML next to the title.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this, including the following in header.php (I've just added some example content);

```
        <?php 
             if ( is_front_page() ) { 
                echo '<div id="homestuff">Home stuff in here</div>';
              } elseif (is_page()) { 
                echo '<div id="pagestuff">'. the_title() .'</div>'; 
              } 
        ?>
```

Take note, there is also a is_home() in Wordpress and it's sometimes easy to get in a bit of a tangle about whether is_front_page() or is_home() is the correct one to use, this stackexchange answer is a good source of info about that;

[Whether to use is_front_page() or is_home() in Wordpress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/30385/when-to-use-is-home-vs-is-front-page)

Comment: but what is the code to gain the title of the page?
because the else if needs to contain first the title and then the other html code

Comment: Or wp_title() outside the loop - Codex entry here - http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_title