# How to Display Background on Interior WordPress Pages But Not Homepage

Tags: wordpress

What is wrong with this syntax? I am trying to make a background container hidden on the homepage and transparent on interior pages on my WordPress site. I put this code in header.php:

```
<?php 
             if ( is_front_page() ) .black_bg{ 

    background:none;
};
              } elseif (is_page()) .black_bg{ 
                 {
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
              } 
        ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing up PHP and CSS there, if you want it in the header you'd do it like this;

```
    <?php
    if ( is_front_page() ) {  ?>

    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        .black_bg { background:none; };
    </style>

    <?php } elseif (is_page()) { ?>

    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        .black_bg { background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); };
    </style>        

    <?php }  ?>
```

If it doesn't work remember a common gotcha relates to whether to use is_home() or is_front_page().  This link is to a question which covered similar ground;

[WordPress conditional statement for front-page or inner page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11709805/wordpress-conditional-statement-for-front-page-or-inner-page)